# Home security system affecting network bandwidth

Tags: networking, router, security, bandwidth

So I reached out my network operator about the slow bandwidth (sometimes slow) that I have at home, and they said that my home security system (HSS) may affect the network bandwidth! Note that my HSS doesn't contain any cameras and doesn't connect to the internet at all, but it's connected to the same telephone operator that my router is connected to, (to make automatic phone calls in case of emergency). Since I don't have experience with networking and bandwidth, I couldn't argue with them.

So is this for real? Does the HSS really affect the bandwidth even if it doesn't have any internet connections?

Thank you everyone for your support.

Comment: What kind of internet do you have? DSL,cable,fibre, or etc.

Comment: I'd say no; if it doesn't use internet then it can't influence the bandwidth. Watching TV doesn't affect your water bill either :)

Comment: If telephone, then I'm guessing DSL. This can be an issue with incorrectly installed filters on your line which could then allow interference between the non-DSL and DSL signals on the line. Does the HSS "phone home" over the phone line or does it connect through the internet router or modem?

Comment: 1) My internet is DSL @cybernard

Comment: 2) @wurtel: yes that's the logical answer I also thought of.

Comment: 3) @music2myear: The home phone is connected through phone line, and my operator said that I don't need the filter since the phone is already connected through a filter in the other room.

Comment: @FeresHenteti  I would still try adding a line filter just to be sure.  Anything that isn't a dsl modem gets the line filter.

Comment: My dad did installation and repair for a west coast TelCo for years, including DSL, and he said filters are best installed between each telephone handset and the wall jack. So, for each phone in your house that connects to a telephone jack, you'd put a filter between the phone and the jack.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is no. (At least not if the equipment is working properly)

Most home security systems will periodically dial in to the security company network and transmit a simple account number with a sensors ok message. This is in case a criminal is intelligent enough to cut your phone line. They will send someone out when it misses the interval. Some wont even do that, they may try to dial you on the account emergency number to see if you are home.

Even if you are on DSL it shouldn't affect the bandwidth in any way by the system periodically dialing. If you do Infact have DSL service music2myears comment is correct, check the filters to any handsets. Disconnect them one by one for troubleshooting, disconnect one then check the bandwidth until you have identified the culprit device.

If your ISP service is delivered through cable or fiber ect, what you were told is absolute non-sense.

Comment: Basically, if it's DSL then the HSS use of the phone line should be the same impact as you using the phone yourself, and this would be easy to test and verify.